# Custom ksort sort multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to order multidimensional array by year and quarter ascendant, I have tried with ksort and it works but I want to create a custom function that does the same thing using algorithms

```
$custom_table['2019-3']['new_members'] = 100;
$custom_table['2019-4']['new_members'] = 100;
$custom_table['2019-1']['new_members'] = 100;
$custom_table['2019-2']['new_members'] = 100;

array    
  '2020-1' =>   
    array 
      'new_members' => string '100'   
  '2020-2' =>   
    array   
      'new_members' => string '100'   

  '2020-3' => 
    array 
      'new_members' => string '100'   

  '2020-4' => 
    array 
      'new_members' => string '100' 

  '2021-1' => 
    array 
      'new_members' => string '100'

  '2021-2' => 
    array 
      'new_members' => string '100'

  '2021-3' => 
    array 
        'new_members' => string '100'

  '2021-4' => 
    array 
        'new_members' => string '100'

  '2022-1' => 
    array
        'new_members' => string '100'

  '2019-1' => 
    array 
        'new_members' => string '100'

  '2019-2' => 
    array 
    'new_members' => string '100'

  '2019-3' => 
    array 
        'new_members' => string '100'
        
  '2019-4' => 
    array 
        'new_members' => string '100'
```

I tried to use bubble sort algorithm but I don't know what i am doing wrong cause it's not working

```
function table_sort($array){
    
    $length = count($array);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        for ( $j =0 ; $j < $length; $j++) { 
            if($array[$i] > $array[$j]){
               $temp = $array[$i];
               $array[$i] = $array[$j];
               $array[$j] = $temp;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to either pass the array as reference or return the new array int the end of that function. Right now, it will take a copy of the array, do stuff with it and just discard it (since you're not returning it.) Basically, what happens in that function currently stays in that function.

Comment: If you're doing this as a learning exercise, then now is a great opportunity to learn some debugging. Have a look at the values of `$i`, `$j`, `$array[$i]`, and `$array[$j]` as you go through the loop; are they what you expect? If not, how might you get a list of the values you need? Hint: the `ksort` sorts arrays by their *keys*, not their *values*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function table_sort($array){
    //keep the original array, to merge at the end
    $original_array_values = $array;
    //add return keys of the array
    $array = array_keys($array);

    $length = count($array);
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $length - 1; $j++) { 
            // echo key($array[$j]) . '<br>';
            if($array[$j] > $array[$j + 1]){
                $temp = $array[$j + 1];
                $array[$j + 1] = $array[$j];
                $array[$j] = $temp;
            }
            


        }//end second loop
    }//end first loop
    //exchange key with value
    $flip_array = array_flip($array);
    return array_merge($flip_array, $original_array_values);

}//end table_sort()
$custom_table = table_sort($custom_table);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).